# CSS background color not highlighing text that has "overflowed"

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm dynamically populating a `<select>` that's scrollable.  I'm able to create it in HTML and jQuery UI.  The problem I'm running into is that when I have a long entry and I scroll to the right (using `overflow: scroll`), the highlight is only as long as the width of the select before you start scrolling.  How do you extend the highlight to the width of the longest entry? (Or the length of the text)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nno335kx/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="div1">
    <ol id="selectable">
        <li>this/is/a/really/really/really/long/path/name.....................................</li>
        <li>Enterprise Service Management/ALMD/alm-manifest-name</li>
        <li>joshtestrepo</li>
        <li>notatestrepo</li>
        <li>vanilla ice cream</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <select id="selection" size="4">
    <option>this/is/a/really/really/really/long/path/name.....................................</option>
        <option>Enterprise Service Management/ALMD/alm-manifest-name</option>
        <option>joshtestrepo</option>
        <option>notatestrepo</option>
        <option>vanilla ice cream</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#selectable .ui-selecting {
    background: #FECA40;
}
#selectable .ui-selected {
    background-color: #F39814;
    color: green;
}
#selectable {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    resize:both;
}
#selection {
    width:250px;
    overflow:scroll;
    resize:both;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $("#selectable").selectable();
});

$("#selectable").selectable({
    selected: function (event, ui) { 
        $(ui.selected).siblings().removeClass("ui-selected"); //forces a single select
    }
});
```

**---UPDATE---**

The answer from @TheUknown works wonderfully for the `#selectable`.  For future reference, to fix a regular `<select>`, try using a variation of `display:table`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4ksc6tm/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because the default display is `list type` which doesnt cover overflown stuff.

Just change it to `inline-block`

```
#selectable .ui-selected {
    background-color: #F39814;
    color: green;
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nno335kx/1/)